How to check tag of spans of opentelemetry in azure app insight
I am using aspnet core with opentelemetry. When I try to set tag in activityEvent. It appears in customdeminsion field in trace log in azure app insight. However. When I try to setTag in activity. I cannot find anywhere to see those tags. Where can I check them? Thanks a lot.

Can you share code what you have tried

If you want to use in activity and not with activity event you can use something like below code in your code:
You can use Console activity to send data without activity event:
using System.Diagnostics;
using Azure.Monitor.OpenTelemetry.Exporter;
using OpenTelemetry;
using OpenTelemetry.Resources;
using OpenTelemetry.Trace;

class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        using var openTelemetry = Sdk.CreateTracerProviderBuilder()
            .SetResourceBuilder(ResourceBuilder.CreateDefault().AddService("MyService"))
            .AddSource("ConsoleApp")
            .AddAzureMonitorTraceExporter(azureExporterOptions =>
            {
                azureExporterOptions.ConnectionString = "InstrumentationKey=344b8760-g6s-f72;IngestionEndpoint=https://eastus-8.in.applicationinsights.azure.com/;LiveEndpoint=https://eastus.livediagnostics.monitor.azure.com/;ApplicationId=a0fh8-8gd8-976f";
            })
            .Build();
        await Rith_func();
    }

    public static async Task Rith_func()
    {
        using var ri_src = new ActivitySource("ConsoleApp");
        using (var rith_act = ri_src.StartActivity("Rithwik_test_activity"))
        {
            rith_act?.SetTag("rith_tag", "rith_value");
            Console.WriteLine("Hello Rithwik Bojja, Activity is started !!");
            await Task.Delay(1000);
            Console.WriteLine("Hello Rithwik Bojja, Activity is ended !!");
        }
    }
}

Output:

